# How do I beat Hino-Enma?

Tags: nioh

I was able to beat the first two bosses pretty simply, but the third boss has been absolutely wrecking me repeatedly and I haven't been able to get more than a few hits in before getting paralyzed, which leads to my quick death.

For anyone interested in how quick I mean, I've recorded videos of some of my fights with her.

- [Example 1](https://youtu.be/77qIR2I6O9w)
- [Example 2](https://youtu.be/Zbd41aUtZdE)
- [Example 3](https://youtu.be/iNmiTx8PS5Y)
- [Example 4](https://youtu.be/_sEyhUUbo4o)
- [Example 5](https://youtu.be/wqoC3yuaWjA)

Is there something I can do to avoid this paralysis? All of her attacks inflict some paralysis, so even if I avoid the beam that insta-paralyzes me, I'll still end up being paralyzed after getting hit a few times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are armors with paralysis resistance. Archer gear if I recall correctly usually rolls with it. Likewise, equip 2 accessories with paralysis resistance.

The rest is pretty SoulsBourne - be patient, time your dodges, slash just a few times, rinse, repeat.

When she is flying you can run up below her and block, and she'll drop on you (causing damage if you don't block). This is the best way to bring her down from flight.

Her attacks are always 2 or 3 combos. Wait or bait the 3rd attack, if you want to play it safe.

Use talisman of sloth if you want to make her slower.

Comment: I'll have to test out the blocking when I get home from work. Do you know where I could get a Talisman of Sloth? This seems really helpful; I'll mark it as accepted once I beat her. :P

Comment: @Vemonus Also check your inventory if you have Antiparalytic Needles and if you do, equip them to a quick selection slot. I don't know which enemies drop them but when I first fought the boss I had about 10 of them. Before or after you do the mission you should also be able to buy them from the blacksmith. The needles will instantly stop the paralyzation effect. Use them if you get hit by the red orb which has the long stun effect. The paralysis resistance eqipment makes the biggest difference though because you will snap out of the effect much sooner.

Comment: @Kodama I have those. I totally forgot that was a thing until you mentioned them. I will have to equip those.

Comment: There are a number of antiparalytic needles available as loot in the side chambers off the last hallway leading to the boss arena. Sometimes these types of games clue you in as to what you need to survive an upcoming encounter.